# Deformation Theorem without a point

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

So I essentially have to prove the deformation theorem, but in this case the domain $D$ contains a point $z_0$ where $f$ may or may not be holomorphic. One path is $\gamma_1$ a circle of radius $r$ around $z_0$ and another path $\gamma_2$ which is the path in which $D$ is bounded by. I need to show that $\int_{\gamma_1}f(z)dz=\int_{\gamma_2}f(z)dz$ and the hint is to use Cauchy's Theorem. Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: make a "slotted washer" with inner boundary $\gamma_1$ and outer boundary $\gamma_2$, and let the width of the "slot" go to zero.

Comment: I can see how this would work but how would this utilize cauchys theorem?

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic everywhere except $z_0$. Therefore, it is holomorphic inside the slotted washer.

Comment: I see, so essentially by using this method i would be showing that both integrals equal 0

Comment: Not quite. Be careful about the direction of travel along these boundaries, and what that means for the sign of each contribution.

Comment: So is the 'slot' between the two boundaries or between one boundary and the point $z_0$?

Comment: I think it makes sense, I would end up showing the the sum of the two integrals equals zero, not necessarily that they both equal zero?

Comment: The region you're integrating around looks like a "C". $z_0$ is in the center of the C, not in the slot (it couldn't be in the slot, since it's assumed to be enclosed by $\gamma_1$).

Comment: You would show that the difference between them is zero. Check your sign conventions for contour integration.